# Magento 1.9 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I have downloaded Magento 1.9 from [Magento 1.9](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror)
Downloaded sample data from [Magento Tech Resources](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download1933)

Everything went well, I have created a New Customer account successfully, Placed an Order and Proceeded to Checkout.

But when I tried to click **Continue button** from **BILLING INFORMATION** TAB with the **Ship to this address** option selected, I can't go to the next step.

> I checked on Network tab and found that **checkout/onepage/saveBilling** status is returning:
>    **(failed) Or Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**.

I tried to select the second option which is **Ship to different address**, and the **SHIPPING INFORMATION** TAB was loaded.

But then again, when I entered a new address then click the Continue button or choose **Use billing address**, I still got the error but this time, it is **checkout/onepage/saveShipping**

Did anyone experience this kind of error before?
Looking forward to a solution.
Thanks

Note: It is a fresh install. No modifications made.

EDIT:  **FOUND THE SOLUTION ALREADY**

> **DISABLED SOME EXTRA SHIPPING METHODS LIKE UPS, DHL, AND ETC. Then it works**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to post the solution that works in order for others to use it as a reference in the future.

The error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

appears when you have an enabled Shipping Method in your store that has not been configured properly. In my case, I found out that DHL, UPS, USPS, and FedEx were enabled but not properly set(I mean the Gateway URLs and other stuff).  I have disabled it and everything works as expected.